# Script that downloads the most recently added image in a Dropbox directory

Tags: python, download, dropbox

I am creating a project for my thesis and I am stuck trying to make a python script that downloads the most resent image from a Dropbox directory. The script I show below can download specific images that I ask but, how can I download the most recently added image in the /photos directory?

```
import dropbox
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("ACCESS_TOKEN")

with open("photo1.jpg", "wb") as f:
    metadata, res = dbx.files_download(path="/photos/photo1.jpg")
    f.write(res.content)
```

Comment: If the /photos directory is a normal filesystem folder, you can use `glob.glob()` to get a list of image files in the directory and then call `os.stat()` on each one to retrieve its metadata, such as creation date, date of last modified, size, etc.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox API doesn't offer a direct way to list the most recent file(s) in a particular path, so you'll need to use the [`files_list_folder`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder) and [`files_list_folder_continue`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder_continue) methods to list all of the contents of the folder, and then sort through them to find the desired file, i.e., in this case, the one with the latest [`FileMetadata.server_modified`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.FileMetadata.server_modified).

Once you find the most recent file, you can then use its [`id`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.FileMetadata.id) or [`path_lower`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.Metadata.path_lower) property as the `path` value when calling [`files_download`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_download) to download the file content.

Comment: In the tutorial, it shows how to get the metadata as:                                                     print('x=', dbx.files_get_metadata('/photos/photos1.jpg').server_modified)                                      
If the "photos" folder has multiple images, how can you print the metadata for each image?

Comment: You can use the 'list_folder' methods linked in my answer above to list the contents of a folder like that. The response will contain a list of the same kind of metadata that `files_get_metadata` returns.