# Script that produces all the names of the files and time they were added in a Dropbox folder

Tags: python, directory, metadata, dropbox

I am trying to create a script that shows the name of the images in a dropbox directory and the time they were added to the folder. To do that I have created gama[entry] that has all the names of the images in that directory. My problem is I don't know how to add those names in the directory in order to produce the metadata. The script below can't work for that reason. How can I add it?

```
import dropbox


dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('ACCESS_TOKEN')

gama={}

dbx.users_get_current_account()
for entry in dbx.files_list_folder('/photos').entries:

   gama[entry]= entry.name
   print('gama=', gama[entry])
   print(entry.name)


   x= dbx.files_get_metadata('/photos/gama[entry]').server_modified
   print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line, you're putting the actual string "gama[entry]" into the path, instead of the value of the variable with that name:

```
   x= dbx.files_get_metadata('/photos/gama[entry]').server_modified
```

You probably meant to do something like this instead:

```
   x= dbx.files_get_metadata('/photos/%s' % gama[entry]).server_modified
```

Or, more directly, without the `gama` variable, that's equivalent to:

```
   x= dbx.files_get_metadata('/photos/%s' % entry.name).server_modified
```

Note that you actually don't need the `files_get_metadata` call anyway though. The `files_list_folder` method gives you the same metadata to begin with, so you can just do:

```
   x= entry.server_modified
```

Comment: Thank you, can I ask you how can I call the most resent image? Can I save the time and use the max() method to find the most resent one?

Comment: @MaxMad Yes, the exact code is up to you, but like discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60781270/1305693 you should get the listing, and find the one with the most recent `server_modified` value. E.g., you might want to get the full list of files and then sort on the `server_modified` key, then take the first one (or last one, depending on which direction you sorted them).